# PHP select random strings from given strings

Tags: php

sorry I am new to PHP. I would like my code to randomly select from these:
'/post371/',
'/post375/',
'/post377/',

but when I tried to access my url it redirects to https://example.com0 , https://example.com1, https://example.com2.

Instead of, https://example.com/post371/ , https://example.com/post375/ , https://example.com/post377/

Here's my code:

```
<?php        
$pagez = array(
        '/post371/',
        '/post375/',
        '/post377/',
    );
    
    if(empty($_GET['redir'])) {
        $_GET['redir'] = base64_encode(home_url() . array_rand($pagez));
    }
?>


    <form id="landing" method="POST" action="<?php echo base64_decode($_GET['redir']); ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="newwpsafelink" value="<?php echo $_GET['code'] ?>">
    </form>
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            document.getElementById('landing').submit();
        }
    </script>
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

array_rand returns a random key from the array

Try this :
`$_GET['redir'] = base64_encode(home_url() . $pagez[array_rand($pagez)])`

Answer (score 1):

The [`array_rand`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) function returns a random **key** from the array. You're really close already - just access the returned element like so:

```
$_GET['redir'] = base64_encode(home_url() . $pagez[array_rand($pagez))];
```

Comment: Thanks this works:     $pagez[array_rand($pagez)]);